# How to create a polydivisible number of 10 digits by solving system of modulo equations?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

A common puzzle, is to create a [polydivisible number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydivisible_number) of 10 different digits (integers from 0 to 9). So the first two digits (from left to right) form a number that is divisible by 2, the first three digits makes a number that is divisible by 3 and so on.

My question is can this number be constructed without making multiples attempt? Making modulo equations and solving that?

### Here is a partial solution (spoilers, try it yourself first)

- The 10th digit is obviously a $%0$ so the whole number is divisible by $10$.
- The 5th digit is divisible by 5, $0$ is not available so it must be 5
- All the even number must be at even positions
- Odd positions then contain odd numbers

And the rest of the solutions in the internet attempt multiple solutions at once and discard some solutions in the $n$-th place thanks to the division rule of $n$.

This is cumbersome, as nobody likes division by 7, one leaves it for last. Before using division-by-7 rule, you get 10 possible solutions that you have to try.

### Question again

Is it possible to write the problem with the following equations and solve them using some algebra:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
n_1,n_3,n_7,n_9\equiv 1 \pmod{2}\\
n_2,n_4,n_6,n_8\equiv 0\pmod{2}\\
n_1+n_2+n_3\equiv 0\pmod{3}\\
10n_3+n_4\equiv 0\pmod{4}\\
n_5=5\\
n_4+n_5+n_6\equiv 0 \pmod{3}\\
\sum_{i=1}^7 n_i 10^{7-i}\equiv 0 \pmod{7}\\
10n_7+n_8\equiv 0 \pmod{4}\\
100n_6+10n_7+n_8\equiv 0 \pmod{8}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

where $\{n_i\}\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, with $n_i\neq n_j$ for $i\neq j$.Breaking down the divisibility by 7 I can get:
$$5n_2+4n_3+6n_4+3(1+n_6)+n_1+n_7\equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

Maybe I am missing something? Note that divisibility rule by 9 does not add anything.

Can this system of equations be solved analytically? Any theorem that could reduce it further?

Comment: I could easily be mistaken.  I don't think this particular problem lends itself well to a formal analytical approach, with equations.  Two approaches come to mind.  The approach you have already started: you can ignore the multiple of 9 issue, because of *casting out 9's*.  For divisibility by $4$, you ignore all but the two rightmost digits (i.e. the 3rd and 4th digits).  For divisibility by $8$, you ignore all but the three rightmost digits.  Divisibility by $3$ and $6$ are both casting out 9 **offshoots**, where the remainder must be $3$ or $6$, when you add the digits.  ...see next comment

Comment: The other approach is simply to use the constraints that you have already begun, and write a simple computer program, to brute force through all of the variations that satisfy your pre-existing constraints.